# Flot time series line not working

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to draw some data with Flot, retrieving the data from a API in JSON format.

```
    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(result){            
        $.each(result, function(key, val){
            var fecha = parseFloat(new Date(val.fecha).getTime());
            var temp= parseFloat(val.tempsensada1);
            d1.push([fecha,temp]);          
        });
    });
    var data1 = [{ data: d1, label: "d1" }];
    var options = {
    canvas: false,
    xaxes: [
        { mode: "time" }
    ],
    yaxes: [
        { min: 0 }          
    ],
    legend: { position: "sw" }
};
$.plot("#box-four-content", data1,options);
```

The problem is that there is no line drawn. But when I populate my `d1` with some dummy data and without parsing the JSON like this:

```
d1.push([new Date("2018-02-10 08:00:00").getTime(), parseFloat("3.8")]);
d1.push([new Date("2018-02-11 09:00:00").getTime(), parseFloat("8")]);
d1.push([new Date("2018-02-12 10:00:00").getTime(), parseFloat("10")]);
d1.push([new Date("2018-02-12 10:10:00").getTime(), parseFloat("4")]);
d1.push([1520344993000, 18]);
```

It works like a charm. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.getJSON()` function is asynchronous, which means the `d1` array is filled with the data after the request finishes. But the rest of your code executes instantly after the request is started when the `d1` is still empty. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2610249) for more information.)

To fix your code you have to put all the code for the chart into the callback function, like this:

```
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(result){            
    $.each(result, function(key, val){
        var fecha = parseFloat(new Date(val.fecha).getTime());
        var temp= parseFloat(val.tempsensada1);
        d1.push([fecha,temp]);          
    });
    var data1 = [{ data: d1, label: "d1" }];
    var options = {
        canvas: false,
        xaxes: [
            { mode: "time" }
        ],
        yaxes: [
            { min: 0 }          
        ],
        legend: { position: "sw" }
    };
    $.plot("#box-four-content", data1,options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that was my problem!